# T-SQL - fiscal quarter

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to arrive at an output like 2011-Q4 (Financial Yr-Qtr)

I can do this by:

```
CASE -- Results: 2011-Q4 (Financial Yr-Qtr)
     WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN concat((YEAR(MyDate) - 1), '-', 'Q4')
     WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN concat((YEAR(MyDate) - 1), '-', 'Q1')
     WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN concat((YEAR(MyDate) - 0), '-', 'Q2')
     WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN concat((YEAR(MyDate) - 0), '-', 'Q3')
 END AS FYrQtr
```

But can the same output be achieved without using CONCAT? (I only have 2008 at work; CONCAT arrived in 2012).

Thanks.

Comment: `CONCAT('X','Y')` = `ISNULL('X','') + ISNULL('Y','')`. Perhaps you could have a try. Also you should get into the habit of explicitly casting numbers to varchar before trying to concatenate them to strings

Comment: Much longer term consider using a calendar table to define your quarters (this may or may not suit your requirements)

Comment: In `2012` you can simply do: `SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(@Date), '-Q', DATEPART(QUARTER, @Date))`

Comment: Something looks wrong here - do you really have `2011-Q4` followed by `2011-Q1` followed by `2012-Q2` and `2012-Q3` in the year 2012? I'd have thought that all bar the first should be using the current year rather than year - 1.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, Actually, you are not right - `CONCAT` is casting the values to `string`. So, this is valid - `CONCAt(10, 'text')`, but this is not `ISNULL('X','') + ISNULL(5,'')`

Comment: I stand corrected. It looks like a very handy function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *this* particular case you can simply use the `+` operator plus some `cast()`:

```
CASE -- Results: 2011-Q4 (Financial Yr-Qtr)
     WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN cast(YEAR(MyDate) - 1 as char(4)) + '-Q4'
     WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN cast(YEAR(MyDate) - 1 as char(4)) + '-Q1'
     WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN cast(YEAR(MyDate) - 0 as char(4)) + '-Q2'
     WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN cast(YEAR(MyDate) - 0 as char(4)) + '-Q3'
END FYrQtr
```

(but note the use of the `cast()` function: the `concat()` does implicit conversion from `int` to char types, while the `+` operator requires that the left part and the right part are char types)

Comment: Although I don't imagine it should come up in this scenario, I'd still try to handle possible `NULL` values in any concatenation.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu In THIS particular scenario there are strong guarantees that the left part and the right part of the `+` expression won't be `NULL`: `MONTH(MyDate)` isn't `NULL` (checked by `CASE`), so `YEAR(MyDate)` isn't `NULL` and the right part is a constant string. Still added some comments on the fact that the proposed solution is for *this* particular case.

Comment: You're right, in this case it wouldn't be an issue, it was more of a suggestion for other scenarios where you use concatenation.